# Как вывести данные, которые я получил при работе с API?

Tags: json, api

Пытаюсь вывести данные, которые я получил после GET ЗАПРОСА по ссылке "https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries", но есть проблема, там есть многомерные массивы.
Я хочу вывести цену "Продажи" и цену "Покупки", при этом перебирая этот массив(декодированный уже) в цикле foreach, но у меня ничего не выводится, кроме предупреждений.

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 39

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 39

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 39

```
define("LINK_CE", 'https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries');
$data_ce = file_get_contents(LINK_CE);
$cource_ce = json_decode($data_ce,true);
foreach ($cource_ce as $value){
            if($value['MarketID'] == 18) echo '<br><br><b>CE(buy/sell)</b>
<p>'.$value['BidPrice'].'</p><p>'.$value['AskPrice'].'</p>';
        }
```

Вот к примеру как я обращался и выводил цены раньше и этот код работал, но я хочу сделать более компактный код.

```
   $ce_buy[0] = $cource_VAL['result']['AskPrice']
```

Comment: Дайте var_dump($cource_ce)

Comment: array(4) { ["success"]=> string(1) "1" ["request"]=> string(26) "/api/v1/getmarketsummaries" ["message"]=> string(0) "" ["result"]=> array(646) { [0]=> array(12) { ["MarketID"]=> string(2) "18" ["LastPrice"]=> string(10) "0.01966998" ["Change"]=> string(5) "-0.05" ["HighPrice"]=> string(10) "0.02014999" ["LowPrice"]=> string(10) "0.01912525" ["Volume"]=> string(11) "11.44106701" ["BTCVolume"]=> string(11) "11.44106701" ["TradeCount"]=> string(3) "822" ["BidPrice"]=> string(10) "0.01951016" ["AskPrice"]=> string(10) "0.01966998" ["BuyOrderCount"]=> string(3) "251" ["SellOrderCount"]=> string

Comment: Вот скрином еще http://prntscr.com/isi0a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно поменялась структура json.

```
define("LINK_CE", 'https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries');
$data_ce = file_get_contents(LINK_CE);
$cource_ce = json_decode($data_ce,true);
if('1' !== $cource_ce['success']){
    die();
}
foreach ($cource_ce['result'] as $value){
    if($value['MarketID'] == 18) echo '<br><br><b>CE(buy/sell)</b><p>'.$value['BidPrice'].'</p><p>'.$value['AskPrice'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Всеравно ошибки выдает. Warning: Illegal string offset 'result' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'result' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'result' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'MarketID' in E:\OSPanel\domains\asentus\index.php on line 43

Comment: затупил. Обновил ответ. В песочнице работает

Comment: Спасибо, работает все.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, отметьте ответ как правильный